# Is it possible to tell if someone is a U.S citizen or not just by looking at their credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report, credit-history

I am not sure if this question fits this stack exchange, but I could not any other that seemed more appropriate. Here it goes.

Say person A is a U.S citizen with 3 years of credit history. Person B is an international (neither citizen nor permanent resident) and has 5+ years of credit history and has lived in the U.S for the past decade on student/job visas. Then my question is, can one determine their citizenship/immigration status correctly by  looking at *only* their credit reports?

Comment: You mean in a US context, correct?

Comment: Yes only in a US context and the answer in your comment does not provide a credible source.

Comment: The issue will be that the information in the credit report is somewhat confidential information to the credit bureaus, and so I don't think it's 100% known what is in them (hence not always a credible source exists).  All that can be said is that nothing is *known* to be in them indicating citizenship.  (Side note, of course the SSN can be queried with the SSA, so this will not be hard to obtain if they want to... you may want to clarify in your question the reason you're asking, if it's not just a random question.)

Comment: @Joe I'm missing how a SSN relates to this question. I have a SSN and I'm not even a US person.

Comment: @RupertMorrish The SSN could (in theory) be used to tell if the person was a citizen, *separately from* the credit report; hence my question of what is driving the question (it may, or may not, matter.

Comment: @Joe what drove me to ask question is this: There seem to be many financial institutions that only serve citizens or permanent residents with SSN; however, their only means of verifying if a potential customer is indeed a US citizens is *asking* them to indicate their citizenship status on the application and requiring a driver license or state id number, both of which is easily obtainable for internationals. 

Thus, by simply indicating (falsely) that one is a U.S citizen, a foreign national can potentially unlock many financial services that are otherwise available only to U.S citizens.

Comment: Since a credit report is tied to a SSN you won't have much luck getting a loan without an SSN.